# Sudo specific command with no password

Tags: sudo

I've got the following entry in `/etc/sudoers` to allow me to run any command after asking for my password

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I also want to run a specific command with no password as part of a script. I've tried putting the following line in `/etc/sudoers`, but it always asks for a password when I run it.

```
gmc ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/hdparm -C /dev/sdc
```

Is there a way to have `sudo` use the specific command before using the general entry?

Answer (score 5):

*Order* of rules is important.

From `man sudoers`

```
 When multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order.  Where
 there are multiple matches, the last match is used (which is not neces-
 sarily the most specific match).
```

So if you have

```
gmc ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/hdparm -C /dev/sdc
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

The the last rule will apply, and a password will be required.

However if you have

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
gmc ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/hdparm -C /dev/sdc
```

Then the NOPASSWD: rule applies.